# Why does JS code "var a = document.querySelector('a[data-a=1]');" cause error?

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors, custom-data-attribute, selectors-api

I've an element in the DOM:

`<a href="#" data-a="1">Link</a>`

I want to get this element via its HTML5 custom data attribute `data-a`. So I write JS codes:

`var a = document.querySelector('a[data-a=1]');`

But this code doesn't work and I get an error in browser's console. (I tested Chrome and Firefox.)

JS code `var a = document.querySelector('a[data-a=a]');` doesn't cause error. So I think the problem is that HTML5's JS API `document.querySelector` doesn't support to look for the number value in HTML5 custom data attribute.

Is this a problem of browser implementation bug or a problem of HTML5's spec relevant to `document.querySelector`?

Then I tested codes below on http://validator.w3.org/:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>An HTML Document</title>
<a href="#" data-a="1">Link</a>
```

They're validated. Since these HTML5 codes are validated. We should can use HTML5's JS API `document.querySelector` to look for this anchor element via its custom data attribute. But tha fact is that I get error.

Does HTML5's spec to HTML5 JS API `document.querySelector` say that this method can not look for an HTML5 data custom attribute with a number value? (An HTML5 spec source is wanted.)

Comment: when using [CSS attribute selectors](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/css/syntax/selectors/attribute.htm), the value should be wrapped in quotes, e.g. `a[data-a="1"]`.

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` is not an "HTML5 JS API". It has absolutely nothing to do with HTML5 whatsoever.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

From [the selectors specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-representation):

> Attribute values must be CSS identifiers or strings.

Identifiers cannot start with a number. Strings must be quoted.

`1` is therefore neither a valid identifier nor a string.

Use `"1"` (which is a string) instead.

```
var a = document.querySelector('a[data-a="1"]');
```

Comment: and if your number is stored in a variable
eg var dataId = 5;
then it should be written out this way
document.querySelector("a[data-a='"+dataId+"']");
this answer helped but I had trouble with the quotes for a bit hope this helps someone

Comment: Note, this can also be written as `document.querySelector("a[data-a=\"1\"]");`.

Comment: The clean way to use a variable here would be `document.querySelector(`a[data-a="${myVariable}"]`);` (SO might fuck with the formatting but i used [backticks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) instead of " " )

Answer (score 9):

You could use

```
var a = document.querySelector('a[data-a="1"]');
```

instead of

```
var a = document.querySelector('a[data-a=1]');
```

Comment: it doesn't work without quote in firefox as of today

Comment: It is what it is.

Answer (score 3):

Because you need parentheses around the value your looking for.
So here : `document.querySelector('a[data-a="1"]')`

If you don't know in advance the value but is looking for it via variable you can use template literals :

Say we have divs with data-price

```
<div data-price="99">My okay price</div>
<div data-price="100">My too expensive price</div>
```

We want to find an element but with the number that someone chose (so we don't know it):

```
// User chose 99    
let chosenNumber = 99
document.querySelector(`[data-price="${chosenNumber}"]`)
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes strings must be quoted and in some cases like in applescript, quotes must be escaped

```
do JavaScript "document.querySelector('span[" & attrName & "=\"" & attrValue & "\"]').click();"
```

Answer (score -3):

Took me a while to find this out but if you a number stored in a variable, say x and you want to select it, use

```
document.querySelector('a[data-a= + CSS.escape(x) + ']').
```

This is due to some attribute naming specifications that I'm not yet very familiar with. Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score -3):

An example with variable (ES6):

const item = document.querySelector(`[data-itemid="${id}"]`);

Comment: it's an incomplete answer, but i think it's not terrible enough to be downvoted.  Note that everything is surrounded by backticks ` but this is recognized here as denoting text literal contents so it formatted everything within instead of displaying the backticks.
`document.querySelector(\`[data-itemid="${id}"]\`);`